# Stock Nexus 5 reboots randomly

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot-loop

I cant take it anymore and even with a full insurance plan, Sprint is not willing to replace my phone with a brand new identical phone. It has had this issue from day one. I think it rebooted itself on its first ride home from the Sprint store when I got it almost a year ago. I have just put up with it over the last few months because besides this issue, I love my phone. I'm worried if I reset it I will lose everything. So first question, what can I expect from a factory reset? What will be saved (via Google profile) and what will be lost?

Ok that question aside, let me now explain exactly what it does. It is completly random. The phone will just freeze on any screen for about 5 to 10 seconds, then reboot. It seems to be a pretty fast reboot. Here is the weird part. There is no logical pattern to when the reboot will happen. It could be during streaming netflix, or browsing a website. It could be when the phone is just sitting on table not being used. It can even freeze right after it just rebooted, ie, the phone reboots due to this issue, then as soob as the unlock screen apears, it could freeze again.

Its different everyday too. On a good day, it may never freeze and reboot ( or at least I dont see it happen). On a bad day, it may freezw and reboot 10 times within 30 minutes. It seems to come in cycles. I wont see it for awhile, then a few days later it will be really bad.

I have recently loaded a ram utilization widget to try to see if I notice a pattern, but so far I havent managed to see the ram usage prior to a freeze. At first it kinda seems like an app could have a memory leak issue. That might explain the randomness of the reboot, but at same time, this hypothesis does not account for the immediate freeze after reboot. RAM utilization would not be an issue immediately after a fresh reboot.

I have also tried installing a log viewer,but so far it has not been much help. I need a recomendation on an app to view the correct log file that might give me a clue as to whats going on. I dont know which log file to view though. I know android is based off Linux, but the log structure may be a little different. Even if it is the same, there may not be any useful info in log right at the freeze point. What I probably really need is to look at some sort of crash/dump file. I get the feeling that may be over my head though.

I need help with this please. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

### Find problem apps by rebooting to safe mode

If your device keeps restarting itself, freezing, crashing, or is slow to respond, it could be caused by an app you’ve installed. You can use safe mode to start up your device with only the original software and apps that came with your phone. If the issues with your device go away in safe mode, the problem is probably caused by a third-party app downloaded on your device.

**Use safe mode to find problem apps**

- Make sure your device's screen is on, then press & hold the Power
  button.
- In the box that opens, touch & hold Power off.
- You’ll see a    “Reboot to safe mode” box.
- Touch OK. Your device will start up in    safe mode.
- Try using your device normally. Remember, you won’t be    able to use
  any installed apps.
- If the problem goes away: Restart your device to exit safe mode.
- Uninstall recently downloaded apps one by one to see if you can
  find the app that’s causing issues.

**If the problem still doesn't go away one more option**

- perform a factory reset

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not a lollipop issue even i had same issue , i gave device to service center where they charged me 300 rs and fixed my power button, there was a issue with power button stuck in because of which nexus was restarting.